# Is it safe to use Double Checking Locking based Singleton in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, final, java-memory-model

There is one of implementations of Singleton in Java listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization):

```java
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static volatile SingletonDemo instance = null;

    private SingletonDemo() {
    }

    public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (SingletonDemo.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new SingletonDemo();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

There is [Java Language Specification 17, paragraph 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) stating that

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

Ok, so imagine that our SingletonDemo class has non-final field. So, concurrent thread will be able to read default value instead of correct value specified in constructor?

Comment: Isn't the answer to double-checked locking always "don't use double-checked locking"? Either it doesn't work, or it doesn't help.

Comment: @user2357112 True, but it is an interesting question. I think it should be answered anyway.

Comment: No, DCL often is really useful, you just should be careful with it. Anyway, it's a common example that listed in many sources. So I just want to determine is it really safe. It's not about Singleton or DCL, it just about Java memory model and threading model.

Comment: See also [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).

Comment: @Radiodef, this article is very old, JMM had changed in Java 5+, so it's not related to my question.

Comment: It is so very much related to your question because it explains exactly why it did not work before and why it does now.

Comment: @WolframNyaa that link is an in depth explanation that answers your question. It has been written based on the current memory model which has not changed for several years now. You should read it (until the end)...

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to implement double-checked locking (DCL) correctly in Java 5 and later.  In Java 4 and earlier, it is not possible due to the fact that the behaviour of `volatile` with respect to synchronization was not properly specified (and in practice was inadequate).

The code you included in your question is a correct implementation for DCL ... when run using a Java 5 JRE or later.

But (IMO), it is not worth using DCL.  Especially if you (or developers coming after you) **don't completely understand** how to do it if correctly / safely.

The performance benefit is simply too small for this to be a worthwhile optimization in a real-life Java application.   (And if it is, you are probably overusing / misusing singletons ... and that will bite you in other ways!)

---

> Ok, so imagine that our SingletonDemo class has non-final field. So, concurrent thread will be able to read default value instead of correct value specified in constructor?

(The quoted JLS text is about an entirely different situation.  It is about `final` fields.  It is not relevant here.  And you cannot infer the behaviour for non-`final` fields with synchronization from the behaviour of `final` fields without synchronization.)

The answer to your question is No.  The code in your question is doing enough to guarantee that a concurrent thread won't see the default value.  To understand why, read the following:

- all of Section 17.4 of the JLS, and
- the last chapter of Goetz et al "Java Concurrency in Practice", which includes a section on DCL (if I remember correctly ...)

Answer (score 4):

Your quote says:

> If final field and constructor finished THEN threads can see initialised value.

It does **not** say:

> If non final field THEN threads can't see initialised value.

The semantics of volatile guarantee safe publication in that example too.

Also you say that DCL is very useful: I'd say that there are better ways that don't require using that complex and error prone construct in almost all situations. In order of preference:

- don't use a singleton at all
- use an enum
- use the initialisation on demand holder idiom

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent thread can see even object's final fields in uninitilized state. Remove volatile from your code and it may happen. In absence of synchronization only thread which creates an object is guaranteed that reference to the object is returned only after constructs finished initialization.

Comment: Ok, but it's obvious. Reads/writes to non-volatile variable are not bound by happens-before, so question is not about this.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting your Wikipedia-link, this would be the most correct double-checking-volatile solution:

```
// Broken under Java 1.4 and earlier semantics for volatile
class Foo {
    private volatile Helper helper;
    public Helper getHelper() {
        Helper result = helper;
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                result = helper;
                if (result == null) {
                    helper = result = new Helper();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Because "the volatile field is only accessed once, which can improve the method's overall performance by as much as 25 percent".

Alternatively you can use the [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom):

```
public class Something {
    private Something() {}

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Which works because during class-loading the LazyHolder `INSTANCE` is not initialized until the class is actually accessed, which is during the `getInstance()` method.

Or just stop doing over-complicated initialization for no particular reason and use the standard eager initialization:

```
static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
```

There are only very rare cases, where lazy initialization actually helps. And that is if your Singleton has a high initialization cost and is - during normal program execution - likely to not be used **at all**. But this case is usually an architectural issue and the lazy-initialization is just a quick & dirty fix.

So you *should* use the eager initialization **unless** you profiled your application and have determined this to be a strongly negative performance issue. But then there are still many other ways to solve this on an architectural level, instead of using a lazy-initialization.